# SGD mini batches - all of the same size?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithms with mini batches usually use mini batches' size or count as a parameter.

> Now what I'm wondering, do all of the mini-batches need to be of exact same size?

Take for example a training data from MNIST(60k training images) and a mini-batch size of 70.

If we are going in a simple loop, that produces us `857 mini-batches of size 70 (as specified) and one mini-batch of size 10.`

Now, does it even matter that (using this approach) one mini-batch will be smaller than the others (worst case scenario here: mini batch of size 1)?
Will this strongly affect the weights and biases that our network has learned over almost all its' training?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, mini batches do not have to be the same size. They are usually constant sized for efficiency reasons (you do not have to reallocate memory/resize tensors). In practise you could even sample size of the batch in each iteration.

However, the size of the batch **makes a difference**. It is hard to say which one is the best, but using smaller/bigger batch sizes can result in different solutions (and always - different convergence speed). This is an effect of dealing with more stochastic motion (small batch) vs smooth updates (good gradient estimators). In particular - doing stochastic size of a batch with some predefined distribution of sizes can be used to use both effects at the same time (but time spent fitting this distribution might be not worth it)

Comment: Great, thanks. One more question though that I couldn't find an answer for: can the way you sample mini-batches improve the result if the training data from which I derive my batches is shuffled every epoch? (of course I'm not talking about a random improvement :D)

Comment: It should not. The assumption is that your mini batches are **uniformly** sampled. The only thing that can happen is that you can **decrease** results by incorrectly sampling (for example in non-random manner). Similarly it is hard to analyze how classical learning methods behave in adversarial setting (when you modify your sampling to focus on harder examples etc.) - then it is more about the heuristics (lack of theoretical results).

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for the insight.